# RShiny: How to have sequential Modals in for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, shiny, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement modal pop-ups into my RShiny app asking the user to input dates. The date inputted would be used in a process within the loop before asking the user for a new date. With my current code, only the modal for the last loop, in this case loop 5, pops up. How would I change my code to have a pop up modal with every loop?

Here is an example of my current code:

```
ui = basicPage(
  actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$show, {
    for(i in 1:5){
      showModal(modalDialog(
        textInput(paste("modal",i,sep=" "), paste("Please enter a date for ID", i, sep = " "),
        placeholder = "Please use format MM/DD/YYYY"),
        footer = tagList(modalButton("Enter"))
        ###Process using inputted date for loop
      ))}})}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There were some similar questions requiring multiple outputs,...you might want to look into `local()`,...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question of why it doesn't work with your code (the answer is a bit complex, but @BigDataScientist is correct, there are many old questions along the same lines of "why does a for loop only output the last result?"). But here's a solution using `shinyalert` modal instead of the shiny modals:

```
NUM_MODALS <- 5

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyalert::useShinyalert(),
  actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog"),
  lapply(seq(NUM_MODALS), function(id) {
    div(id, ":", textOutput(paste0("modal", id), inline = TRUE))
  })
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$show, {
    for(id in 1:5){
      shinyalert::shinyalert(
        type = "input",
        text = paste("Please enter a date for ID", id),
        inputPlaceholder = "Please use format MM/DD/YYYY",
        inputId = paste0("modal", id)
      )
    }
  })

  lapply(seq(NUM_MODALS), function(id) {
    output[[paste0("modal", id)]] <- renderText({
      input[[paste0("modal", id)]]
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```